# Where provide enum manipulation methods?

Tags: c#, methods, enums

I have several enums:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public enum A {a, b, c, d};

    public class ClassB
    {
        public enum B {b1, b2, b3, b4};
        public enum C {c1, c2, c3};
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now I need to perform some operations with enums, to example:

- Return list of all or some members of enum;
- Translate enum to text (to example, `A.a` should be displayed as "Condition A" to the user, `B.b1` as "Option 1")

And my problem is to organize those methods.

There are many of enums and I need to *link* methods to some of them

### Question: where do I store methods to manipulate different enums inside my application?

Should I create a class per enum? Or use custom class to manipulate all enums and name methods with corresonding enum name?

`Enum` is not a class, it can't hold static methods, ideally I would want them to be inside. This would be very convinient, whenever I would be able to type `A.` and intellisence would offer me:

`a, b, c, d, A[] FilterValues(bool condition), string[] AllValuesTranslated(), string TranslateMembmer(A member)`

I hope the question is clear (don't know how to explain what I need shorter, sorry).

Comment: If your `enum` is no longer just a simple value with a convenient human-readable name for development purposes, I'd say it's probably a case for promoting it to a `class`.

Comment: This is Java's one advantage over C#.

Comment: You could use extension methods for some of those enum tools. Although it's sometimes hard to make them reusable for any enum type, because you may need generics which cannot be constrained to enums.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, most of time I'll need enum functinality as it is (setting value, serialize/deserialize). It might be an easy task to do with `class`, but I don't know how to mimic `enum` with `class`. Common extension methods and marked with attributes `enum` values to define behaviour (solution of Elie) seems much better idea to me.

Comment: @sinatr Although that solution is a common workaround to these apparent limitations, I personally avoid defining attributes that contain localisable strings and instead use the enum value as a key into a resource dictionary to get any strings. The extension method route is often used, but you are bleeding methods onto the Type class when not really needed. Another route is simply to code generate per enum or use Jon Skeet's Unconstrained Melody library to use generics.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, attribute doesn't contains a string, it contains an ID for string. More specifically, I have a solution to my problem now, where I assign attribute to the `enum` (not values), which is a type of a class inside static localizable class. Then `enum` value itself is name of the static string property inside that class. So when I need to get a list of localized enum values (to display it inside `ComboBox`), I have extension method which look for attribute, find a type of class and use reflection to read translated text (the content of this class is translated when lng changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few utility extension methods that could help:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Usage:

```
var listOfValues = typeof (A).ToList();
var listOfKeyValuePairs = typeof(A).ToListOfKeyValuePair();
var dictionaryOfValues = typeof(A).ToDictionary();
```

Given the following enum:

```
public enum A
{
    [EnumValueDescription("This is a")] a = 1,
    [EnumValueDescription("This is b")] b = 2,
    [EnumValueDescription("This is c")] c = 3,
    [EnumValueDescription("This is d")] d = 4
};
```

And the following custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Enum | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class EnumValueDescriptionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string StringValue
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }

    public EnumValueDescriptionAttribute(string value)
    {
        this.StringValue = value;
    }
}
```

And the following extension method:

```
public static class EnumExtentions
{
    public static List<Enum> ToList(this Type type)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(type)
                    .OfType<Enum>()
                    .ToList();
    }

    public static Dictionary<int, string> ToDictionary(this Type type)
    {
        return type.GetEnumValues().Cast<Enum>().ToDictionary(Convert.ToInt32, e => e.GetDescription());
    }

    public static List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> ToListOfKeyValuePair(this Type type)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(type)
                    .OfType<Enum>()
                    .Select(e => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(Convert.ToInt32(e), e.GetDescription()))
                    .ToList();
    }

    public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        return value.GetDescription(null);
    }

    public static string GetDescription(this Enum value, string defaultValue)
    {
        var allFields = value.GetType().GetFields();
        if (!allFields.Any())
            return defaultValue;

        var targetField = allFields.FirstOrDefault(fi => (fi.IsLiteral && (fi.GetValue(null).Equals(value))));
        if (targetField == null)
            return defaultValue;

        var attrib = targetField.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumValueDescriptionAttribute), false)
            .OfType<EnumValueDescriptionAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        return attrib == null ? defaultValue : attrib.StringValue;
    }
}
```

It's not completely clear what other manipulation methods you require.

Comment: The idea of marking enum values with attribute and then use common extension methods is really nice. I can define several attributes for different purposes and then use different methods what will proceed according to the available attributes. And actually in most cases I can use type name to switch between different tasks inside single extension method (may looks not as flexible, but should be pretty enough) Also thanks for that `typeof(A).ExtensionMethod()`, saved me some time ^^.